# ArcGIS Online - Not all layers in tile layer showing when published. Why?

Tags: arcgis-online, tile-package

I georeferenced a scanned map and added it the "my content" in my ArcGIS Online account as a tile package. I then published it so I could use it in my mapping application. However, only a fraction of the map is showing in the application.

The Tile Layer (Hosted) Settings tells me that 13.5% of the tiles are available. Why isn't the rest of the map available?

The entire map will show in the mapping application if I zoom out a lot - but at that scale the map is a thumbnail and of no use to me. Can someone please explain what's going on and how to fix it?

The map is the size of Bermuda. I have already added a similar raster map, and that layer says that 100% of its tiles are available and I have no problem. I know it has something to do with the % tiles available, I just don't know how to make the rest available.

Comment: If you check now, is it still 13.5%?

Comment: It has not changed.